# OData vs oAuth -- What is the difference?

Tags: oauth-2.0, odata

I am a bit confused about the difference between OData and OAuth? Are they both protocols for authorization? Or they are used together?

Answer (score 3):

Thay are totally different things:

**[OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/overview)**

is a protocol for querying an endpoint and service information.

You are able to perform select and filters against it.

> OData (Open Data Protocol) is an ISO/IEC approved, OASIS standard that defines a set of best practices for building and consuming REST APIs. It enables creation of REST-based services which allow resources identified using Uniform Resource Locators (URLs) and defined in a data model, to be published and edited by Web clients using simple HTTP messages.

The formal documentation is a bit broad, but I believe the examples are pretty interesting, note the `filter` parameter:

```
https://example.org/Airports?$filter=contains(Location/Address, 'San Francisco')
```

See [source tutorial](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/).

**[OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/)**

is a protocol for authorization.

> OAuth 2.0 is the industry-standard protocol for authorization. OAuth 2.0 focuses on client developer simplicity while providing specific authorization flows for web applications, desktop applications, mobile phones, and living room devices. This specification and its extensions are being developed within the IETF OAuth Working Group.

**[OpenIDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect)**

OpenIDC is an OpenID based authentication standard on top of OAuth.

I think it's worth to mention because this often is mentioned together with OAuth.

> OpenID Connect is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol, which allows computing clients to verify the identity of an end-user based on the authentication performed by an authorization server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the end-user in an interoperable and REST-like manner.